# For a readmade garments online shopping portal, Joomla or shopping application?

Tags: extensions

I am in the process of developing a website (online shopping portal) for readymade garments shop. My exposure to Joomla (which is essentially CMS) and believe that there are shopping applications like VirtueMart and HikaShop gives me an option to go for Joomla. On the flip side, I ask myself if I just want to develop a shopping application, why Joomla and not applications like ZenCart? So, my query is developing a shopping application using Joomla gives any advantage which makes it worth to go?

Comment: There are both many con's and pro's for each solution, but in the end it runs down to your specific needs and what you require the shop to do. If you JUST need a shop, then you should consider that while there a shop applications for it, it's not designed to be a shop on it's own like cs-cart and all the other options out there. - _also_ Due to the reasons above, this kind of question is primarily opinion based, and doesn't really belong here :) Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is **Cost of Opportunity**.

You can just install Joomla, any E-Commerce extension or template, learn how to customize, override, translate labels and launch your site in a short period.

On the other hand, developing a shopping application can be as rewarding as your available time to develop it. It is not a piece of cake, you have to understand Joomla development and E-commerce features in deep. E.g Payment gateways.

I usually solve these dilemas asking to you:

- Do you want to sell readymade garments?
- Do you want to sell consulting services for an e-commerce site?
- Do you want to sell an E-commerce extension for Joomla?

You can only answer **Yes** to one of them. ;-)